# Emploi de "(Avoir) le blues"

Tags: anglais, anglicismes

Je sais l'origine et la signification de l'expression *(avoir) le blues*. Je pensais que c'est un anglicisme mais aujourd'hui j'ai lu cet article :

https://www.lemonde.fr/sciences/article/2019/10/14/le-blues-des-chercheurs-francais_6015488_1650684.html

> Le blues des chercheurs français.

Je me demande pourquoi un journal comme *Le Monde* utilise une telle expression. Est-ce une expression courante ? Pourquoi aussi *le* et pas *les* ? [À propos, TLFi, n'en parle pas : https://cnrtl.fr/definition/blues de cette signification].

Comment: Rien d'étonnant que le mot ne soit pas dans le TLF. Le TLF c'est  le [Dictionnaire de la langue du XIXe et du XXe siècle (1789-1960)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A9sor_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise). Mais il est dans [le wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/blues).

Comment: Il est tout aussi correct d'écrire «  j'ai lu aujourd'hui cet article » que « aujourd'hui j'ai lu cet article ». Quelqu'un te l'a corrigé mais ce n'était pas justifié. Juste pour que tu le saches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mon édition du *Petit Robert* (1993) signale que mot *blues* (prononcé [bluːz] ou francisé en [bluz] et toujours singulier, invariable avec un « s ») est entré dans la langue française :

- en tant que genre musical en 1919,
- en tant que synonyme de cafard en 1985, avec une citation tirée de l'[*Express*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Express) datée de 1987.

> Les militaires ont le blues.

En tapant la phrase exacte dans un moteur de recherche, voici ce que je trouve.

> Cibles d'attaques, les militaires ont le blues. ([BFMTV](https://www.bfmtv.com/police-justice/cibles-d-attaques-les-militaires-ont-le-blues-1233489.html), 18/08/2017)

> Les militaires ont le blues, pourquoi ?([JDD](https://www.lejdd.fr/Politique/Vincent-Desportes-Notre-defense-se-degrade-619069-3141800), suite à une interview d'un général de l'armée française, 14/07/2013)

Le mot est bien ancrée dans la langue française, mais je pense toujours ressenti comme un anglicisme, fort probablement parce qu'il a gardé la prononciation anglaise.

Ce n'est ni étonnant, ni choquant, que le journal *Le Monde* et la presse en général utilisent le mot dans ce sens là.

Dans *Le Monde* du [5/25/2017](https://www.lemonde.fr/m-perso/article/2017/12/05/ma-ruche-a-le-blues_5224870_4497916.html), avec un joli jeu de mot :

> Ma ruche a le blues.
>   Depuis quatre ans, les abeilles de notre reporter apiculteur ont le bourdon.

Dans *Le Monde* du [26/12/2018](https://www.lemonde.fr/m-le-mag/article/2018/12/21/les-climatologues-ont-le-blues_5400708_4500055.html) :

> Les climatologues ont le blues.

Dans *Le Parisien* du [06/05/1998](http://www.leparisien.fr/hauts-de-seine-92/les-animateurs-culturels-ont-le-blues-06-05-1998-2000052632.php) :

> Les animateurs culturels ont le blues

Dans [20 minutes](https://www.20minutes.fr/sport/2554891-20190702-coupe-monde-feminine-valenciennes-blues-apres-mois-pure-folie) du 2/07/2019 :

> Coupe du monde féminine: Valenciennes a le blues.

[Le Dauphiné](https://www.ledauphine.com/france-monde/2019/08/29/attaques-secheresse-loups-l-elevage-francais-a-le-blues) du 29/08/2019 :

> Attaques, sécheresse, loups : l’élevage français a le blues

---

Détail anecdotique. L'écrivain [Boris Vian](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Vian) grand amateur de jazz a écrit « *blouze* » (en parlant du style musical) dans son roman *[Vercoquin et le Plancton](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vercoquin_et_le_Plancton)*. J'ai voulu vérifier si l'orthographe avait été reprise, et je l'ai rencontré dans des forums de personnes dont le français est, disons, « approximatif » à l'écrit.

Comment: C'est un anglicisme dans le sens que son origine anglophone est toujours perçu mais je ne le ressens pas, même dans le sens _cafard_, comme à éviter comme d'autres anglicismes peuvent l’être.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Je ne le ressens pas non plus, mais certaines personnes oui. Signalé comme tel dans le *dictionnaire culturel en langue française* et figure dans le dictionnaire des anglicismes, alors je me suis demandée pourquoi.

Answer (score 1):

On trouve d'autres article typifiés ainsi.

Le blues des producteurs d'huile d'olive d'Espagne face à Trump
https://www.boursorama.com/actualite-economique/actualites/le-blues-des-producteurs-d-huile-d-olive-d-espagne-face-a-trump-ade328b52ea1f1df67ad02473bd369f1

Consommation : le blues de la classe moyenne
https://www.lepoint.fr/societe/consommation-le-blues-de-la-classe-moyenne-08-10-2019-2339942_23.php

Après la faillite de Thomas Cook, le blues des tour-opérateurs
https://lexpansion.lexpress.fr/actualite-economique/le-blues-des-tour-operateurs_2101237.html

Le blues des élevages bovins allaitants
http://www.lafranceagricole.fr/actualites/bourgogne-le-blues-des-elevages-bovins-allaitants-1,10,518779571.html

Le blues des donneurs de sang des champs
https://www.centre-presse.fr/article-705266-le-blues-des-donneurs-de-sang-des-champs.html

L'idée derrière ce terme est simplement celle de conférer un état de malaise, de déclin et/ou de mécontentement ; l'idée que l'on retrouve dans « blues » selon son acception anglaise est essentiellement absente sauf par le biais de la conséquence inévitable que l'état de chose rapporté ne peut pas manquer de causer chez les personnes impliquées plus ou moins de mauvaise humeur (ce qui n'est pas de la tristesse), et peut-être aussi de la tristesse, mais pas à un tel point qu'il s'agisse d'états de mélancholie dignes de titres d'article. Pourtant,  « the blues » n'est pas autre chose qu'une certaine tristesse assez profonde.

En se référant aux dictionnaires sur le Web on ne trouve pas autre chose que la signification usuelle.

https://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-french/have-the-blues (traduction)

- avoir le cafard *ou* avoir le blues

https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/blues/

- cafard, bourdon

De surcroit, il ne semble pas que dans l'anglais provenant des ÉUA il existe une telle  acception pour « blues ».

Il me semble que comme assez souvent lorsqu'il s'agit de s'inspirer de la langue et de la culture anglo-saxonne, ici très précisément de la culture américaine, on n'a pas pu s'empêcher de se jeter sur un concept  qui fait parler de lui et de l'appliquer en le « déportant » à une situation qui convient à certains, le résultat étant que alors que l'on emprunte un terme en vue d'avoir une référence commode aux connotations qu'il a dans sa langue parce qu'elles ne sont pas dans la notre, il en embrasse de nouvelles (déjà dans la notre) et ce n'est plus grand chose qu'une combinaison de lettres avec un lustre remarquable.

Selon cette compréhension je me demanderais pourquoi  cette solide tendance journalistique survit si bien ; elle n'apporte rien à la compréhension, tantôt elle décrit une chose (malaise) tantôt une autre (mécontentement) ou bien les deux et cela au moyen d'un terme que l'on trouve synonyme de « cafard » ou « bourdon », un terme qui ne convient pas pour ces choses-là.

Le choix du genre (le, les) ne suit pas une rationnelle bien définie ; le genre musical est indénombrable (« uncountable ») en anglais (verbe au singulier et l'état d'âme est pluriel (« plural ») (verbe au pluriel), d'où la confusion entre les deux que l'on n'a pas cherché à éviter, mais que, bien sûr,  en raison de contextes différents on évitera pratiquement toujours à la lecture.  Si vous voulez dire que le TLFi ne mentionne pas le sens relatif à la description d'un malaise ou d'une mauvaise situation, c'est exact, mais tous les autres dictionnaires ne le comprennent pas non plus.
Pour caractériser cet usage avec plus de précision, il faut remarquer que très souvent, si pas presque toujours, le terme apparait dans le titre mais pas dans le reste de l'article, les rares occurrences dans le texte sous le titre donnant parfois l'impression d'un terme mal assimilé auquel on s'essaie toujours. C'est donc un terme, selon l'acception que l'on devrait lui attribuer mais manquante dans les dictionnaires, qui reste très douteux et donne l'impression d'un certain tape à l'œil dans une presse à sensations.